# Is there any way to load user details stored in useContext earliear

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-context

Context provides the user's details but it takes sometimes to load first time or while refresh the page so checkcontext() function set isLogin to false so what can I do to that context load properly , it works correctly when context is loaded

#### It work's when I not comparing with context and waiting for complete load

```
const MyOrder = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(true);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);

  const history = useHistory();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([
    {
      OrderedItems: [],
      contactNumber: "",
      deliveryCharge: 0,
      mealType: "",
      orderBy: "",
      placedAt: "",
      shippingAddress: "",
      totalPrice: 0,
    },
  ]);
    console.log(context);
    checkContext();

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Grid container align="center" sx={{ marginTop: "30vh" }}>
          <Skeleton variant="rounded" width={210} Height={200} />
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        <>
          {isLogin ? (
            <div>
              <h2 style={{ marginTop: 100, textAlign: "center" }}>My Orders</h2>
              <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                  aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                  id="panel1bh-header"
                >
                  <Typography
                    sx={{ width: "5%", flexShrink: 0, textAlign: "left" }}
                  >
                    No.
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ width: "10%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                    Meal Type
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ width: "20%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                    Order Date
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    sx={{ width: "28%", flexShrink: 0, textAlign: "center" }}
                  >
                    Address
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    sx={{ width: "10%", flexShrink: 0, textAlign: "center" }}
                  >
                    Delivery Charge
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    sx={{ width: "10%", flexShrink: 0, textAlign: "center" }}
                  >
                    Total amount
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
              </Accordion>

              {orders.map((order, id) => (
                <div>
                  <Accordion>
                    <AccordionSummary
                      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                      aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                      id="panel1bh-header"
                    >
                      <Typography sx={{ width: "5%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                        {id + 1}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography sx={{ width: "10%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                        {order.mealType}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography sx={{ width: "20%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                        {order.placedAt.substring(0, 10)}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography sx={{ width: "30%", flexShrink: 0 }}>
                        {order.shippingAddress}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography
                        sx={{
                          width: "10%",
                          flexShrink: 0,
                          textAlign: "center",
                        }}
                      >
                        {order.deliveryCharge}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography
                        sx={{
                          width: "10%",
                          flexShrink: 0,
                          textAlign: "center",
                        }}
                      >
                        {order.totalPrice}
                      </Typography>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                      <TableContainer>
                        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 500 }} aria-label="simple table">
                          <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                              <TableCell>No.</TableCell>
                              <TableCell>Item Name</TableCell>
                              <TableCell>Quantity</TableCell>
                              <TableCell>Price/Item</TableCell>
                              <TableCell>Total</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          </TableHead>
                          <TableBody>
                            {order.OrderedItems.map((item, id) => (
                              <TableRow
                                key={id}
                                sx={{
                                  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
                                    border: 0,
                                  },
                                }}
                              >
                                <TableCell>{id + 1}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.ItemName}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.Quantity}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.ItemPrice}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  {item.ItemPrice * item.Quantity}
                                </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            ))}
                          </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                      </TableContainer>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                  </Accordion>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <AlertDialog open={!isLogin} />
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyOrder;
```

UserContext.jsx

````
import { React, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();
const DispatchUserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUser = async () => {
            const token = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt");
            try {
                const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9000/OTS/user/profile", {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        authorization: token,
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    },
                });

                const data = await res.json();


                if (data.status !== "success") {
                    setUser(null);
                } else {
                    setUser(data.data);
                    console.log("From UserContext" + data);
                }


            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        fetchUser();
    }, [])

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
            <DispatchUserContext.Provider value={setUser}>
                {children}
            </DispatchUserContext.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { UserContext, DispatchUserContext, UserContextProvider };```
````

Comment: What exactly is the issue/question? You want to load the context value earlier? Earlier than what?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your user context gets its data from some API - which will take some time and you can't avoid it.

Logically in the userContext you could add one property isInitialized and set it to true once you get the data from the endpoint. And render an loading indicator while isInitialized is false.

Additionally to avoid the loading screen on multiple visits to the site is you could use localStorage to store the user and then load the user immediately into context. e.g

Somewhere you probably have some code that fetches the user

```
  // Assuming we're in some SessionManager
  // component or wherever you're handling authentication
  const SessionManager = ({ children }) => {
    const context = useContext(UserContext)
    fetchUserData = async() => {
      const response = await fetch(...);
      const user = await response.json();
      context.setUser(user); // assuming this function set's the user in context
      Storage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchUserData(); 
    }, [])

    if (context.initializing) return <div>...loading</div>

    return children;
  }

  // now in the UserContext file assuming you have something like this
  const userFromStorage = JSON.parse(Storage.getItem('user')) || null;
  const isExpired = new Date(userFromStorage.expirationToken) < new Date();

  export default createContext<UserContextType>({
    user: userFromStorage && !isExpired ? userFromStorage : null,
    initializing: userFromStorage && !isExpired,
   })
```

This change would make sure that on subsequent visits to the site you would show the cached user initially until the updated version is loaded.
Things to be careful about if you take this approach:

- Don't store sensitive data in Storage (no passwords/tokens, except for expiration token)
- Check the expiration token before setting the user from cache

Comment: Yes below is my UserContext

Comment: If you analyze the code I wrote you, you could modify your code and it should work.

Besides your posted code is still incomplete, what is checkContext(), setisLogin, setIsLoading ? ... etc